# Is a flight number unique for the schedule, origin and destination?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, aircraft

For example, if we have a flight with a code `SU0102`, does it always goes from Sheremetyevo to John F. Kennedy or the origin and destination points can change for this flight? The same about schedule: does a flight `SU0102` always leave at 15:40 and arrives at 17:10 or the hours can change?

In short words, can the schedule, origin and destination change for a flight with a certain number and if so is it frequent?

Comment: You are developing a flight related app? hehe ;)

Comment: With all the mergers and codeshares, flight numbers have shifted around quite a bit on the Big 3 US carriers recently. On top of this there are not enough four-digit flight numbers to go around now (and it would be a monumental effort to update the software to use five digits, or allow letters), so we have increasingly compressed ranges— I see the same flight number on both the outbound and the return legs even on some mainline flights these days, e.g. [AA362](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL362).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing anywhere to say that the airline won't change the flight number or reuse the same flight number to connect different destinations.

Case in point: [United flight 237](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/travel/flightstatus/results.aspx) contains 2 different segments flown by 2 different aircraft today so in essence you can look at it as 2 different flights.

On occasion airlines change flight numbers for the same destinations due to various conditions most notable one is an accident for example [Moscow - Hong Kong is now flight SU212 but it didn't used to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot_Flight_593) and so on.

Just about the only thing that you can expect is that flight number for a regularly scheduled flight will change sufficiently enough in advance of bookings/reservations so that airline doesn't have to notify clients of the change midstream.